# Different return value console/javascript with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript/jquery/html, and I have to develop a little simulator with html and javascript.

I have an array with stored html id and a function that should update input based on the passed state.

The code is something like this:

```
var dev_array = [["#8_1", "#8_2"], ["#8_3", "#8_4"], ["#8_5", "#8_6"], ["#8_7", "#8_8"]];

function send_dev_state_ctrl(state){
   dev_array.forEach(function(entry){
      for (i = 0; i < entry.length; ++i) {
         console.log(entry[i]);
         var input =$(entry[i]);
         console.log(input);
         input.value =value_hash_dev[i];
         handle_ctrl_send(input);           
      }
   });
 }
```

The console show:

```
#8_1
[input#8_1, context: document, selector: "#8_1", jquery: "1.10.1", constructor: function, init: function…]  
...
```

If I digit $("#8_1") in console, I have the following output:

```
[<input type=​"hidden" id=​"8_1" name=​"8:​1" value=​"1">​]
```

What should I do to have the same return value in javascript?

Comment: [ID's cannot start with a number](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number)

Comment: @simone: They can in HTML5.

Comment: For some reason the console chooses to represent the *same* value differently. You shouldn't be concerned by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but doing:

```
  var input =$(entry[i])[0];
```

It returns the same value of console.

I don't like it, but it works.

Comment: `$(entry[i])[0]` is the first *DOM element* inside the jQuery object. As I said in my comment, you shouldn't worry about what the console shows. Assuming that `$` refers to jQuery in both cases, you will actually get the same value back.

Answer (score -1):

You are not $'ing up your console.log you are just spitting out the array value.

Change this:

```
console.log(entry[i]);
```

To this:

```
console.log($(entry[i]));
```

And you will get the same result for both.

---- EDIT ----

My bad i misread the question, so you are correct doing

```
var input =$(entry[i])[0];
```

Will work, this is because `$(entry[i])` is an object and the first value in that object is the DOM element which is accessed by doing `$(entry[i])[0];`.

Another method would be do to this:

```
var input =$(entry[i]).get(0);
```

Which pretty much does the same thing.

Unfortunately there is not much other way of doing it.

Comment: I think you overlooked `var input =$(entry[i]); console.log(input);`. The output of `console.log(entry[i]);` can be seen at the beginning of the quoted output: `#8_1 [input#8_1, ....`.

Comment: Well this is completely dependent on what perusopersonale want the 2 console.logs to be, do you want both to be #8_1 or both to be [input#8_1, ...